# Prevent unauthenticated users from navigating to a route using a URL in a flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, routes, flutter-web

I'm attempting to create a web app in Flutter that would ideally work like a website. Users would log in and be able to see their dashboards with private information, but there are certain screens with public information that anyone could navigate to using a dynamic route URL like: `myflutterapp.com/feed/usersPublicInfo`, where this link could be posted to another website, for example, and the user could go straight into this route.

Clearly using named Routes is a solution I would need, but then what is preventing someone from going directly to a route where private information is? Or at least preventing a user from going to a page with `null` information and causing the widgets to crash?

**Solution idea 1**

Use named Routes and after the login screen, pass the user variable to each screen, and have a nullcheck before the route is generated. If it's null, that means someone skipped some routes and they are sent back to login

**Solution idea 2**

If possible, use a mix of named routes and "unnamed" routes, such as the feed, dashboard, and login screen. Once the user makes it to the dashboard, all routes are handled using Navigator.push(), preventing them from being reached from a URL

**Other Solutions?**

I'm fairly new at flutter and flutter web, so I could be going at this problem all wrong. I would appreciate some advice.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
static Future<void> init() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    if(kIsWeb) {
      final String defaultRouteName = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.defaultRouteName;
      if(!(defaultRouteName == 'home' || defaultRouteName == 'login' || defaultRouteName == '/')) {
        SystemNavigator.routeUpdated(
           routeName: '/',
           previousRouteName: null
        );
      }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you put some explanation what it does? And how it solved the issue?

Comment: 如果你愿意尝试一下google Translation:
你需要先简单了解三点
1,WidgetsBinding.instance.window.defaultRouteName是引擎获取到的平台的默认路由名称(在web平台就是url中hash部分)
2,在web中刷新浏览器或者点击链接打开新页面都是会重新构建整个应用的，这也是你错误的原因，整个应用都被刷新，路由参数当然也没有了。
3,你可以在WidgetApp类的源码中看到创建Navigator的实现: 如果存在WidgetsBinding.instance.window.defaultRouteName就使用它作为默认路由名称并且会覆盖你自己配置的默认路由名称

知道这些之后，那我们只要在WidgetApp构建前修改window.defaultRouteName就行。用WidgetsBinding.instance.window.defaultRouteName和你自己的路由表进行对比(根据你的需要进行检查)。如果满足条件就放行，如果不满足就调用SystemNavigator.routeUpdated进行修改

...抱歉我不会英语，不能帮你太多。如果有哪里我没说清楚的地方可以继续问我。

Comment: (dart) '#' + WidgetsBinding.instance.window.defaultRouteName
==
(javascript) window.location.hash

Comment: could someone explain how the code above works?

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1 looks good to me.

For my suggestion use [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) for state management. Here's my example base on my context :

```
    routes: {
      "/": (context) => MainPage(),
      "/detail": (context) => UserDetailPage(),
      "/other": (context) => OtherPage(),
    },
 builder: (context, child) {
          return Consumer<UsersProvider>(
            child: child,
            builder: (context, provider, child) {
              if (provider.isLoading) {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                );
              }

              final value = provider.user;
              if (value == null) {
                return Navigator(
                  onGenerateRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
                      settings: settings, builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
                );
              }

              return MultiProvider(
                providers: [
                  ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UsersProvider()),
                  ChangeNotifierProvider(
                      create: (context) => InvoicesProvider()),
                  ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => EventsProvider()),
                ],
                child: child,
              );
            },
          );
```

Basically use builder in `main.dart` and defines routes, then inside builder use Consumer were child is the initial route `MainPage()` so if the user already login they will go there, and if not, base on flag which is in my context is `isAdmin` they will redirect to LoginPage(). So if they try to go to detail or other by using url they will redirect to `LoginPage` anyway.

Here's my UserProvider:

```
  getUser() async {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged.listen((currentUser) async {
      _isLoading = false;
      if (currentUser == null) {
        _user = null;
        notifyListeners();
        return;
      }
      final data = await Firestore.instance
          .document("users/${currentUser.uid}")
          .snapshots()
          .first;
      if (data.exists) {
        print(data.data);
        if (data.data['is_admin'] == true) {
          _user = User.fromMap(data.data);
          notifyListeners();
        }
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
```

So if the user `isAdmin` it will return their value. I hope you can understand my explanation. I hope this is helpful for you too.

Comment: Nice solution. I implemented it, working well. Thanks